# Where can I find a simple explanation or lectures of QM and QFT?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education

If anyone knows any books or video lectures that explain QM and QFT in a simple way, with more focus on the ideas and concepts behind it than the details of calculus. I need to conceptually understand QM and QFT, and the ideas behind the calculus: what it means and what we are doing with it, but I don`t need to solve equations.
It is for a theoritical research I am doing, not for exams.

Comment: You have to be more specific on what you mean as "simple way". There is no indication of your educational level in your profile to guide us. If you mean "simple way" for a high school student, it is not possible to do this. There is no way to explain simply calculus , the mathematical method, except hand waving, not a book. There is a series of open video lectures of MIT for serious students.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jANZxzetPaQ  https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/8-323-relativistic-quantum-field-theory-i-spring-2008/

Comment: I have edited my question I hope it is more clear now.